# Docker Volume not persisting data

Tags: bash, docker

I am learning docker using [Practical Docker with Python](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484237830)
 book.

In chapter 5, the author is demonstrating how to use docker volume to persists data. He does this using these commands:

```sh
# create a volume
docker volume create volume-test

# create a container and attach the volume 
docker run -it --name volume-test --mount source=volume-test,target=/data-volume ubuntu bash  

# write some data to volume-test volume
echo "This is a file created from container having kernel `uname -r`" > docker_kernel_info.txt
```

Then he stops and removes the container:

```sh
docker stop volume-test
docker rm volume-test
```

After that, he creates a new container with the same volume attached and tries to read the `docker_kernel_info.txt` file created by the first container:

```sh
$ docker run -it --name volume-test --mount source=volume-test,target=/data-volume ubuntu bash
```

```
$ cd /data-volume/
```

```
$ cat docker_kernel_info.txt
```

This is a file created from container having kernel
4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs.

This is where the problem starts. 
When I create the second container, I can't see any file in `/data-volume` directory. In fact, it is empty.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `# write some data to volume-test volume` - did you `cd` into `data-volume` directory before that? If you just do `> docker_kernel_info.txt` it will create a file in your working directory, which most probably isn't `/data-volume` directory.

Comment: no, he didn't mention to change directory. He said the output would be written to the volume.

Comment: okay, I changed the directory before creating the file and It is working now. So only data written inside `/data-volume` would be persisted, right?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the /var/lib/docker/volumes and run **ls** command. There are several directories that they named of random hashed string. then Run **ls** command from these directories. Maybe you found your mount-point directory.
for example:

```
ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/e9500fce66618003a372d9915137847c207b44432fdb503fb56b6c9dd507ce6c/_data
```